# Issue running sed to replace a string in file

Tags: regex, linux, shell, awk, sed

**I have a file** **"input.txt"** that contains the following at **Line Number 18:**

**entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = "Admin"**

**I want to replace** `"Admin" with {"Admin", "root"}` 
---> "root" is just an example name, It can be anything.

So after the replacement the **Line Number 18** should become

**entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "root"}**

Another run of the sed command with different input name: **"user1"**

**entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "root", "user1"}**

And so on, there can be multiple entries into this **Line Number 18** of File **input.txt**

...

**I would like to remove it as well.**

That is if the file **"input.txt"** contains following at **Line Number: 18**

**entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "root", "user1"}**

Then upon removal of **"root"** it should become :

**entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "user1"}**

Upon Removal of **"user1"** it should become:

**entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = "Admin"**

Comment: can you provide exact input and desired output? looks like answers below not what exactly wanted

Comment: Do you want solution specifically in sed? It's not the best way to do what you want

Comment: Actually the system I have might not have other utilities. sed and awk are present. perl is not available.

Comment: Awk could be better here

Comment: Or i would use python it's usually preinstalled on Linux

Comment: No $entry is copy paste from my script. entry= $2. Its the second argument to my script. $2 = "Any godamm name"

Comment: @Tegra: In my [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33054239/4892253) i've used gnu sed 4.2.2 on linux. If your environment is different or you use a different implementation of sed i can provide a fix.

Comment: You removed your attempted code in your latest edit.  That basically makes this off-topic for StackOverflow -- we are happy to look at your attempt and maybe suggest a different approach; but no code at all means we can't really tell how much you know and which parts you need help with.  Please revert or refactor your latest edit.

Comment: @tripleee That attempted code was for a different input, it does not work here, hence I removed it. Secondly the attempted code and associated text was the primary reason for all the confusion, everybody trying to help, were having I think. So I think the question now looks very neat and simple.

Comment: I would start by formating the question in order to get proper help. Your question is confuse, make it clear,  "__i have this__" and  "__I need this__". I would close this question  without hesitation based on **"unclear what you're asking**"

Comment: Dear Pedro, Have a look, "I have this" "I want this" was present in the question just highlighted them for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly what do you want: start from this input file:

```
# file input.txt
# line 1
# line ...
# line 17
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = "Admin"
```

Using this sed instruction (with relaxed space tolerance):

```
ENTRY='new_user' && sed '18s/=\s*{\?\s*\(".*"\)\s*}\?\s*/= {\1, "'"${ENTRY}"'"}/' input.txt > output.txt
```

To obtain this:

```
# file output.txt
# line 1
# line ...
# line 17
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "new_user"}
```

As you request you can apply the sed command multiple times to append new entries to the 18th line.

Then you can remove the last entry one by one (till eventually return to the original input.txt) with this:

```
sed '18s/=\s*{\s*\("[^"]*"\)\s*,\s*\("[^"]*"\)\s*}/= \1/; 18s/=\s*{\s*\("[^"]*"\)\(\(\s*,\s*"[^"]*"\)\{1,\}\)\s*,\s*"[^"]*"\s*}/= { \1\2 }/' output.txt
```

To remove entries i considered two cases: when there is only one `${ENTRY}` (to know when remove curly braces) and when there are 2 or more `${ENTRY}` repeated.

**UPDATE** this version, similarly to the *adduser* version accept a shell variable to remove a specific user:

```
ENTRY='user3' && sed '18s/=\s*{\s*\("[^"]*"\)\s*,\s*\("'"${ENTRY}"'"\)\s*}/= \1/; 18s/=\s*{\s*\("[^"]*"\)\(.*\)\(\s*,\s*"'"${ENTRY}"'"\)\(.*\)\s*}/= { \1\2\4 }/' output.txt
```

It works, only note that i've considered **Admin** untouchable.

**NB** note that the remove sed regex does not require you to check the line before: if the line is ending with the single `...= "Admin"` simply nothing happens.

**UPDATE-2**: taking my cue from Ed Morton, you can also put these two functions in your `${HOME}/.bashrc` (or `${HOME}/.profile` or equivalent if you use another shell):

```
function AddUser18() { USER="${1}"; FILE="${2}"; sed -i~ '18s/=\s*{\?\s*\(".*"\)\s*}\?\s*/= {\1, "'"${USER}"'"}/' "${FILE}"; }

function DelUser18() { USER="${1}"; FILE="${2}"; sed -i~ '18s/=\s*{\s*\("[^"]*"\)\s*,\s*\("'"${USER}"'"\)\s*}/= \1/; 18s/=\s*{\s*\("[^"]*"\)\(.*\)\(\s*,\s*"'"${USER}"'"\)\(.*\)\s*}/= { \1\2\4 }/' "${FILE}"; }
```

I've added the `-i~` switch to sed to modify the file in place and make a backup copy of the prevision version with a `'~'` suffix. 
You cam use these function simply in this way:

```
source ~/.bashrc  # only if you are using the same shell where you modify .bashrc
AddUser18 user3 "path/to/the/file"  # to add a new user
DelUser18 user3 "path/to/the/file"  # to remove it (or another)
```

If the *file* you want to modify it's always the same you can also hardcode the path in the function (so FILE will be `FILE="path/to/the/file"` in both functions).

Comment: @Tegra i've updated my answer to match your updated question

Comment: Hi @Gsus. The insert works like butter, however, the remove should also take input as "name", and remove only that name.

Comment: @Tegra: i've updated my answer to remove a specific user. Read the note below the updated code and good users managing :)

Comment: @Tegra: another update to make the operations easier

Comment: Glad to have been of help, happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `sed`,

Add:

```
sed 's/\(= *\)"\([^"]\+\)"/\1{"\2", "$entry"}/' yourfile
```

Remove:

```
sed 's/\(= *\){"\([^"]\+\)", "$entry"}/\1"\2"/g' yourfile
```

**Test:**

```
$ cat f1
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = "Admin"

$ sed 's/\(= *\)"Admin"/\1{"Admin", "$entry"}/' f1 > f2
$ cat f2
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "$entry"}

$ sed 's/{"Admin", "$entry"}/"Admin"/g' f2
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = "Admin"
```

Comment: Hi the problem is this inly works once. I would want to repeat another addition of this command but it does not append the new "$entry" in the file with the required format.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your command is that you are replacing the first `}` in the line for `$entry`.

You could do the whole thing in one expression to avoid this

To add:

```
sed 's/= \([^=]*\)/= {\1, "'"$entry"'" }/' file
```

To remove:

```
sed 's/= {\("[^"]*"\), "'"$entry"'" }/= \1/' file
```

.

These assume that there is only one occurence on the line and that `attempt` can be different strings.

Comment: Dear 9 9 ... The command works fine for the first entry, However when I try to run it a second time the output becomes: 

entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {{{"Admin", "root" }, "gadre" },

It should be:

entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "root" , "gadre" }

Comment: @Tegra Add that comment to the question with formatting and I'll have a look

Comment: @99 Added the comment in Edit:

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use perl, but this should work with `sed(1)` in a similar way.

To append an entry `$entry` (remember to escape the `$` with a backslash):

```
perl -pe 's/= {?("[^"]*"(, "[^"]*")*)}?/= {$1, "\$entry"}/' input_file
```

To delete a given entry `$entry`:

```
perl -pe 's/({)?"\$entry"(?:, |(})?)/$1$2/g; s/, }/}/g; s/{("[^"]+")}/$1/g' input_file
```

Tested with some sample data and it seems to be working. The command to delete is smart enough to delete entries from the middle of a list, from the beginning, and from the end; it is also smart enough to transform entry lists that are 1 element after removal from `{"entry"}` back to `"entry"`, which is what seems to be desirable (since the input file with 1 entry does not group it inside brackets). If that's not the case, it's easy to remove it (let me know if you have trouble).

**UPDATE**

You mentioned in the comments that you can't use perl because it is not available in the machine this needs to run. As I expected, it will work in `sed(1)` in a very similar way; you just have to use `\1` and `\2` for the capturing group variables instead of `$1` and `$2`, and use sed's extended regex mode by invoking it with the `-E` flag.

To append an entry:

```
sed -E 's/= {?("[^"]*"(, "[^"]*")*)}?/= {\1, "\$entry"}/' input_file
```

To delete an arbitrary entry (again, it is smart enough to know how to delete from the beginning, end or middle of an entry list):

```
sed -E 's/({)?"\$entry"(, |(})?)/\1\3/g; s/, }/}/g; s/{("[^"]+")}/\1/g' input_file
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work :(.  

sed -i~ -e '18 s/= {?("[^"]*"(, "[^"]*")*)}?/= {$1, "\$entry"}/' input_file

Does not insert the entry in line 18

Comment: @Tegra `sed(1)` doesn't use perl's `$1` syntax for captured groups. I believe you'd have to use `\1`. [Is there a reason you don't want to use perl?]

Comment: I can't use perl..the machine where this is supposed to be run does not have it

Comment: @Tegra See updated answer. I made a few changes and it now works with `sed(1)`. The most important part is to use sed's extended regex mode (`-E`) and use `\1` instead of `$1` for the capturing variables names.

Answer (score 0):

It's still not entirely clear but this may be what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS  = "[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*"; OFS  = " = "
    sfs = "[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*"; sofs = ", "
    split(cmd,tmp)
    act = who = cmd
    sub(/=.*/,"",act)
    sub(/[^=]+=/,"",who)
    who = "\"" who "\""
}
{ gsub(/[{}]/,"",$2) }
act == "add" { $2 = $2 sofs who }
act == "del" {
    split($2,subflds,sfs)
    $2 = ""
    for (i=1; i in subflds; i++) {
        if (subflds[i] != who) {
            $2 = ($2 ? $2 sofs : "") subflds[i]
        }
    }
}
$2 ~ sofs { $2 = "{" $2 "}" }
{ print }
```

.

```
$ cat file
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = "Admin"
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "root"}
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "root", "user1"}

$ awk -v cmd='add=user2' -f tst.awk file
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "user2"}
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "root", "user2"}
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "root", "user1", "user2"}

$ awk -v cmd='add=some name or other' -f tst.awk file
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "some name or other"}
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "root", "some name or other"}
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "root", "user1", "some name or other"}

$ awk -v cmd='del=user1' -f tst.awk file
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = "Admin"
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "root"}
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "root"}

$ awk -v cmd='del=root' -f tst.awk file
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = "Admin"
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = "Admin"
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "user1"}
```

You don't say what you want done if there's no users left in the list after a deletion:

```
$ awk -v cmd='del=Admin' -f tst.awk file
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth =
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = "root"
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"root", "user1"}
```

or if you try to add an existing user:

```
$ awk -v cmd='add=Admin' -f tst.awk file
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "Admin"}
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "root", "Admin"}
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "root", "user1", "Admin"}
```

or if you ask to delete a user that doesn't exist:

```
$ awk -v cmd='del=stranger' -f tst.awk file
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = "Admin"
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "root"}
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "root", "user1"}
```

Or I expect many other scenarios I haven't thought of but whatever it is you need to do is all just trivial tweaks to handle - you just need to think of these and any other rainy-day scenarios you might have to deal with and include the input/output in your question to clarify your requirements.

BTW any solution you get (sed especially) I would test with these unusual user names:

```
$ awk -v cmd='add=a'"'"'\\tweird&=set\\1/"of chars"' -f tst.awk file
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "a'\tweird&=set\1/"of chars""}
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "root", "a'\tweird&=set\1/"of chars""}
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "root", "user1", "a'\tweird&=set\1/"of chars""}

$ awk -v cmd='del=A.*' -f tst.awk file
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = "Admin"
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "root"}
entry({"servicectl"}, alias("servicectl", "status")).sysauth = {"Admin", "root", "user1"}
```

because it's extremely likely you'll get highly undesirable results. Awk handles it just fine because awk is operating on literal strings but sed cannot operate on strings and so has to deal with regexp metacharacters plus it's own delimiters plus backreferences, etc. and, typically, it can't.